# Difference between n-body collision detection and pairwise collision detection?

Tags: collision-detection

I'm confused as to the difference between the two. I thought they were both the same but I'm reading some papers that focuses more on solving the n-body collision detection problem over the pairwise collision detection problem. What are the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pairwise collision detection is a base case of n-body collison detection. Papers which focus more on n-body collisions apply pairwise collision concepts to general cases; so they really are conceptually *almost* the same thing.